# Как вывести количество использованных каналов в Asterisk?

Tags: python, asterisk, voip

Доброго время суток, коллеги.

Нужно вывести  как-то с Asterisk количество использованных каналов. 
`core show channels` показывает все каналы, а мне нужно только количество
Может кто подскажет?

Стучусь к Астеру как то так:

```
import asterisk.manager
from asterisk.agi import *    
agi = AGI()
    manager = asterisk.manager.Manager()

    manager.connect('000.000.000.1')
    manager.login('login', 'passz')

    manager.command()
    agi.send_command()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну как то так получилось

```
import asterisk.manager
manager = asterisk.manager.Manager()

manager.connect('000.000.000.1')
manager.login('login', 'passz')

ter=manager.command("core show channels count")
print(ter.response[3])
nums = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', ter.response[3])
print (nums[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!
Попробуйте команду

> core show channels count

Правда в любом случае понадобится немного распарсить ответ. Ну либо в вашем выводе подсчитать кол-во строчек (минус шапку и футер вывода).

Comment: Спасибо я это  знал , придётся видимо всётаки  парсить .

Comment: У меня на подобном вся статистика в Zabbix держится